# how to return array using for loop with async fetch inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I'm trying to create an array of responses from a fetch request, but I'm not sure where things are going wrong with awaits I place in the loop. `console.log(response)` gives TypeError: undefined is not an object and when I try `console.log(resp)` I get a console.error

```
const routesArray = async (userLocation, arr) => {
    let result = [];
    let temp = [];
    temp.push(userLocation);
    const updated = temp.concat(arr);


    let origin = updated[0].lat + "," + updated[0].long;
    let destination = updated[updated.length - 1];
    for (let i = 0; i < updated.length; i++) {
        let resp = await fetch(
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" +
                origin +
                "&destination=" +
                destination +
                "&key=" +
                GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY +
                "&mode=transit&region=sg"
        );
        let response = await resp[0]["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"]
        console.log(response);
        result.push(response);
    }
    return result
};
```

Comment: the value of `await fetch` is still a response object, on which you need to call `.json()` and again await the resolution.

Comment: A `Response` doesn’t have a `0` property. You forgot a step in between: you need to read the text of the response as — presumably — JSON, e.g. by calling `(await resp.json())[0]["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"]`.

Comment: Consider using `Promise.all()` here instead of awaiting the `Promise` in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
await resp[0]["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"]
```

with

```
(await resp.json())[0]["routes"][0]["legs"][0]["steps"]
```

Or why not:

```
(await resp.json())[0].routes[0].legs[0].steps
```

This is needed because `resp` is a response object, which does not yet expose the data. For that you must call one of its asynchronous methods, like `json()`, which return a promise of their own.

BTW: the error you got was not on `console.log(response)`, but on the above line.

If you still get errors, then make sure that you got the data structured as you expected it:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(await resp.json()));
```

This will show you the data. Make sure it is an array. If it is not, the code will need to be adapted accordingly, because the `[0]` part will fail.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. After adding that in I get TypeError: undefined is not  an object (evaluating '_context.sent[0]["routes]) but I'm not sure where _context.sent is coming from

Comment: Can you debug, and print out `console.log(JSON.stringify(await resp.json()));`?

Comment: Ok thanks for providing that line, was quite confused when to use await.

Comment: Actually I think the response is not an array (as your code suggests), but an object with the `routes` property, so check that, and if so, drop the first `[0]`